# Array is completely empty after values are inserted into it

Tags: java, split, java.util.scanner

I am trying to insert values taken from user input (in a single line, seperated by spaces) into an `array`. My code is as following:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        String st="";
        
        while(s.hasNextLine())
            st=s.nextLine();
        
        String[] str=st.split(" ");
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));
    }
}
```

When I run the code, the compiler doesn't even ask for inputs and instead shows the output as `[]`. I don't understand what's wrong here. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: If I omit the `while()` loop I get a `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: Your input has only 1 line?

Comment: Use If condition in place of while or add a relevant break condition in while loop hence the control can come out of the loop and execute further.
After u run the code just enter the input string in the console and u will get the outpup.

Comment: Tried with if, it's the same

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behaviour you describe. When I run your program, I can enter as many lines as I want. Only when I type ctrl-D, the program goes on to print the words of the last line entered.

Answer (score 0):

It should run in while loop like this

```
class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    String st="";

    while(true){
        System.out.println("Enter value");

        st=s.nextLine();

        String[] str=st.split(" ");

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));
    }

}
}
```

Comment: It will ask input to enter.  You have to run and then enter value , it will console out. I tested

Answer (score 0):

Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
String st="";

```
while(true){
    System.out.println("Please Enter value");

 
     st=s.nextLine();

     String[] str=st.split(" ");

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String st = "";
        System.out.println("Enter the input string:");

        if (s.hasNextLine())
            st = s.nextLine();

        String[] str = st.split(" ");

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));
    }
}
```

Just changed the While condition to if condition and added sysout.
Output:

```
Enter the input string:
test this program
[test, this, program]
```